# How do I uninstall Ubuntu from my MacBook and replace it back to mac?

Tags: uninstall, macbook

I recently switched my old 2006 I believe MacBook to Ubuntu because I wanted to try it out for a couple of things. I decided to reformat since I didn't have the space to dual-boot, but now when I want Snow Leopard back for my MacBook it doesn't let me install. It asks what disk I want to install to, but none show up. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have to format your HD back to HFS+ first, thats the filesystem OS X needs to be installed on, you can do this using the installation disk.

So after booting from cd just click on **Utilities** on the top tabs, select **Disk utility** and reformat your HD to **Mac OS Extened Journaled**

after this is done you'll be able to install OS X again.

Answer (score 2):

You should first boot from Live CD and there format with gparted, then install OSX again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have either a Linux Live CD like System Rescue CD or Ubuntu Desktop CD to boot and reformat the HDD (gparted is a good GUI tool) to HFS+ so as to install OS X (10.6). Otherwise if you have a OS X 10.6 Install DVD, you can boot (press option) with the install DVD and use the Disk Utility to delete the Linux partitions (or LVM stuff) and recreate partitions, reformat as HFS+, then install on the desired partition.

If you just want to try something out on Linux, running it as guest OS using VirtualBox may be a better/free option;-)